# combine selected column multi file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, columns

I have multiple files (~15), each with multi column data (tab seperated). For example:

**File1**

```
aa1    399     1815
aa2    1908    4064
aa3    4523    5656
```

**File2**

```
bb1    5304317    5305057
bb2    5305057    5305824
bb3    5306871    5307875
```

etc.

I want to read the 2nd column of each file and print them next to each other, to create a 15 column output. For example:

**Output**

```
399     5304317    7526    12455
1908    5305057    8195    14538
4523    5306871    9216    15150
```

Each column is from different file. Notice the first column of **Output** is the 2nd column of **File1**, the sectond column of **Output** is the 2nd column of **File2**.

I thought of using paste. But it puts the whole data from each input file. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Do all of the files have the same number of lines?

Comment: number of lines and columns will be same. But i want selected column from each file to be joined

Comment: In the example output, where is that 7526 figure coming from?  Can't see it in File1 or File2.

Comment: @steve: Based on the description of the problem, 7526, 8195, and 9216 come from File3, as 12455, 14538, and 15150 come from File4.

Answer (score 0):

For 3 files, each with 3 columns, you could use something like:

`pr -m -t -s file1 file2 file3|awk '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",$2,$5,$8)}'`

You might also wrapper this with some thing that would count the number of files and fields per file, but this should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay not doing it as a one-liner you could do

```
for file in $(ls File*); do
  awk '{print $2}' < $file > $file.col2
done
pr -m -s *.col2 > merged.txt
rm -f *.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `paste` could prove suitable after all ?

```
$ paste <(cut -f2 file1) <(cut -f2 file2) <(cut -f2 file3) <(cut -f2 file4)
399     5304317 7526    12455
1908    5305057 8192    14538
4523    5306871 9216    15150
$
```